# How to code 4 relays to go off in intervals and not in sequence?

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, relay

Code :

```cpp
//FOR AEROPONIC SYSTEM WITH ROOM TEMPERATURE AND HUMIDITY SENSOR
//AND 4 GROW CHAMBERS WITH DIFFERENT SPRAYING TIME

// RELAY CONTROL
#define RELAY1_PIN 2
#define RELAY2_PIN 3
#define RELAY3_PIN 4
#define RELAY4_PIN 5

//Libraries
#include <DHT.h>;

//Constants
#define DHTPIN 6
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

//Variables
int chk;
float hum;
float temp;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("SENSOR RUNNING");
    dht.begin();

    pinMode(RELAY1_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RELAY2_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RELAY3_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RELAY4_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    delay(2000);
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    if (isnan(h) || isnan(t))
    {
        Serial.println("CONNECTION ERROR");
        return;
    }
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(t);
    Serial.print(" *C ");
    Serial.println(" ");
    delay(2*1000);
    {
        // FOR RELAY
        digitalWrite(RELAY1_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(2*1000); // wait for 2 second ON
        digitalWrite(RELAY2_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(3*1000); // wait for 3 second ON
        digitalWrite(RELAY3_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(4*1000); // wait for 4 second ON
        digitalWrite(RELAY4_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(5*1000); // wait for 5 second ON

        digitalWrite(RELAY1_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(RELAY2_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(RELAY3_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(RELAY4_PIN, LOW);
        delay(5*60*1000); 
    }
}
```

This code doesn't do what I want. How do I make them independent?

Comment: Please post an actual **question** and not code. What do you want to actually achieve? I and many others will not bother to look at your code until we know what we need to answer. Clearly explaining your problem then asking a specific question will result likely in help.

Comment: Indent your code properly. As it is, there's no way it'll compile, and as you should be able to see, it's exceptionally difficult to follow the flow.

Comment: think about your title ... `not in sequence` requirement makes no sense ... what if `in intervals` happens to be `in sequence` ... do you want to prevent relay activation if that happens?

Comment: Although the question is **far** from clear, it looks like the answer may be for you to learn how to [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that might help you; leaving out the temperature and humidity stuff:

```
// constants
// number or relays
const int relays = 4;

// pins for the relays
const int relayPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};

// relay cycle times
const unsigned long relayTimes[] = {
     5*60*1000, // 5 min
     60*60*1000, // 1 Hour
     2*60*60*1000, // 2 hours
     12*60*60*1000 // 12 hours
  };

// relay on durations
const unsigned long relayOntimes[] = {
    1000, // 1 second
    10*1000, // 10 seconds
    60*1000, // 1 minute
    60*60*1000 // 1 hour
  };

// timing for the relays
// storing the last time
unsigned long relayElapsed[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

// state of each relay
int relaystate[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

// helper function to process each relay
void relay_helper(unsigned long t, unsigned long &elapsed, int pin, int &state, unsigned long delta, unsigned long ontime)
{
  // depending on the state we do different things
  switch (state)
  {
  case 0: // state 0 is off, wait until time has passed
    if ((t-elapsed) > delta)
    {  // then
       state = 1; // set the state to on
       elapsed = t; // reset the time
       digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); // turn on
    }
    break;
  case 1: // state 1 is on, wait until time has passed
    if ((t-elapsed) > ontime)
    {  // then
       state = 0; // set the state to off
       elapsed = t; // reset the time
       digitalWrite(pin, LOW); // turn off
    }
    break;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  for(int i = 0; i < relays; i++) // for each pin
  {
    pinMode(relayPins[i], OUTPUT); // set it to output
    digitalWrite(relayPins[i], LOW); // and turn it off
    relayElapsed[i] = start;
  }
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long tm = millis();
  for(int i = 0; i < relays; i++)
  {
    relay_helper(tm, relayElapsed[i], relayPins[i], relaystate[i], relayTimes[i], relayOnTimes[i]);
  }
  // do other loop stuff
}
```

The basic idea is that the only way to do thing simultaneously is to do things in sequence really fast, we can't use delay() because it is a busy loop, nothing else can happen during delay(), so we keep track of the time and when it is time to turn on the relay we turn it on, and when it is time to turn it off we turn if off.

Another option would be to write a class per relay:

```
class Relay
{
public:
  Relay(int pin, unsigned long delta, unsigned long ontime);
  ~Relay();

  process(unsigned long t);

private:
  unsigned long delta;
  unsigned long ontime;
  unsigned long last; // elapsed
  int pin;      
};
```

Then one can create an array of these:

```
Relay[] relays = {
    Relay(2, 5*60000, 1000),
    Relay(3, 60*60000, 10000),
    Relay(4, 2*60*60000, 60000),
    Relay(5, 12*60*60000, 60*60000)
  };
```

put the code from setup into the constuctor, and the code from the helper into process, and finally call it in a loop in loop.

The first way shown is how one would do it without C++ classes, and the second way is with them!